# bash: script containing forked process hangs when executed via backtick

Tags: bash, fork

My overall purpose is to be able to run script t1.sh, which launches a program that will persist after the script finishes (calculator in this example). t1.sh then echoes the associated PID, which can then be used in some other script, t2.sh, that calls t1.sh.

This issue arose in a larger script, but I think I've isolated it to the following.

t1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-calculator &
PID=$!
echo $PID
```

Running `./t1.sh` starts the calculator, immediately spits out the pid, and gives a new prompt.
However, running `A=$(./t1.sh)` (or with backticks), the script seems to "hang" until the calculator window is closed. Same for this script, t2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
B=$(./t1.sh)
echo $B
```

Nothing is echoed until the calculator window is closed.

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening, and
2. How do you prevent it?

Thanks in advance for any words of wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because the capturing expression is waiting for standard input to close. If you rewrite the script

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-calculator >/dev/null &
PID=$!
echo $PID
```

You should be good.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Just to clarify, the problem was that the capturing expression was waiting for calculator to send something to stdin, but it never did, so the script just hung, correct? I guess I mistakenly thought that forking it would itself prevent this from happening.

Comment: You can test that out in the terminal: `while((SECONDS<3));do echo $SECONDS;sleep 1;done &`. The fact that there is still output even though the jobs is backgrounded means it's still attached to standard input.